# Can someone help me prove that $\tau(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, divisor-counting-function

Can someone help me prove that $\tau(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a perfect square.

So basically I have to prove that $\tau(n)$ is odd iff $n = k^2$ for some integer $k$.

$\tau(n)$ is the function which gives the number of positive divisors of n, including n itself.

Comment: What is $\tau(n)$?

Comment: What is $\tau$ here?

Comment: $\tau(n)$ is the function which gives the number of positive divisors of n, including n itself.

Comment: $\displaystyle \tau (n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} 1 = \sum\limits_{\substack{d|n \\ d \le \sqrt{n}}} 1 + \sum\limits_{\substack{d|n \\ d > \sqrt{n}}} 1$

Comment: @JérémyBlanc It isn't a duplicate because I asked for a certain way to prove it, using n=k^2.

Comment: @CatherineWong I don't think your comment "because I asked for a certain way to prove it, using $n=k^2$" really makes a lot of sense. As Jérémy Blanc pointed out, your question really is a duplicate (if you still don't think so, then I would recommend brushing up on some basic propositional logic). A user with nick Nick (odd coincidence) answered your question but was very concise. My answer below spells things out a bit more. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bijection between the divisors of $n< \sqrt n$ and the divisors of $n>\sqrt n$, defined by $d\longmapsto \dfrac nd$ (this bijection goes both ways). This bijection gives an even number of divisors, since $d\neq \dfrac nd$.
There is one more divisor (hence an odd number of divisors) if and only if $\sqrt n$ is an integer, i.e. $n=k^2$ for an integer $k$.